# Cannot open Firefox add-on using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch file that opens links and programs and I want it to open a page using firefox that links to a firefox add-on.

```
 cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox" 
 start  firefox.exe chrome://fireftp/content/fireftp.xul
```

Nothing happens after I open the batch file but it works fine with normal http or www links. How can I fix it?

I read that the add-on link is a local file so I added

```
file:///chrome://fireftp/content/fireftp.xul
```

and now the firefox application starts but there is no page opened.

I also tried manually opening the file of the add-on in

```
file:///C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/w0sxtro2.default-1416128364358/extensions/%7Ba7c6cf7f-112c-4500-a7ea-39801a327e5f%7D/content/fireftp.xul
```

but it gave me an error saying:

> Remote XUL

Comment: why you are trying to open chrome specific link with firefox?

Comment: Hello, I am not opening a chrome link but the extension FireFTP for firefox. I installed it and that is the link that appears on http bar. I only copied it and I also dont know why it is chrome.

Comment: Here it is :
[link] (http://i64.tinypic.com/8wcx8p.png)

Comment: try with `start  "" firefox.exe chrome://fireftp/content/fireftp.xul`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this code but firefox did not run.

Comment: Remove the chrome protocol and simply refer to the file via your file system e.g. `file:///C:/path/to/extension/fireftp.xul`. You could also try just dragging and dropping the file into Firefox to load it.

Comment: Hello @ManoDestra, thank you for your help. I have tried this code
`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe file:///C:\Users\Marcial\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w0sxtro2.default-1416128364358\extensions\{a7c6cf7f-112c-4500-a7ea-39801a327e5f}\content\fireftp.xul` 
Firefox now runs and loads the page but displays an error
_Remote XUL: This page uses an unsupported technology that is no longer available by default in Firefox._

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/859304

Comment: I will study this solution. Thank you.